# Durandal 2.1 - accessing view from viewmodel?

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I have the following in my viewmodel:

```
 dialog.getContext().reposition(vm);
```

But it's not working, because I'm supposed to be passing the `view`, not the `viewmodel`.  How can I - from within a viewmodel - get access to its corresponding view?

Comment: the attached function in the viewmodel is passed in the viewmodels corresponding view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Access the view from your viewModel You have `detached`,`compositionComplete`, `attached`, and `compositionComplete` handlers to choose from.

For example from `attached`:

```
function attached(view, parent) {
   console.log("This is the current view",view);//this will log the view HTML
  $(view).find(".smallLoader").fadeOut();// Now fadeOut .smallLoader from this view
}

var viewModel = {
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Home',
    attached: attached
};

return viewModel;
```

Comment: You have access to the view from binding, bindingComplete, attached, compositionComplete and detached. Not activate